# App is crashing without showing any error

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception

```
CoreFoundation`__CFTypeCollectionRetain:
    0x10fd3d830 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x10fd3d831 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x10fd3d834 <+4>:  testq  %rsi, %rsi
    0x10fd3d837 <+7>:  je     0x10fd3d842               ; <+18>
    0x10fd3d839 <+9>:  movq   %rsi, %rdi
    0x10fd3d83c <+12>: popq   %rbp
    0x10fd3d83d <+13>: jmp    0x10fd3ac80               ; CFRetain
    0x10fd3d842 <+18>: leaq   0x337eed(%rip), %rax      ; "*** __CFTypeCollectionRetain() called with NULL; likely a collection has been corrupted ***"
    0x10fd3d849 <+25>: movq   %rax, 0x368378(%rip)      ; gCRAnnotations + 8
    0x10fd3d850 <+32>: int3   
->  0x10fd3d851 <+33>: callq  0x10fed9cec               ; symbol stub for: getpid
    0x10fd3d856 <+38>: movl   $0x9, %esi
    0x10fd3d85b <+43>: movl   %eax, %edi
    0x10fd3d85d <+45>: callq  0x10fed9d46               ; symbol stub for: kill
    0x10fd3d862 <+50>: nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

Log:

> objc[24778]: Class MFData is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME and /Users/hemang/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8B9DCA42-1446-4D56-871A-2CFBC43DF81A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5CAB5F60-AF92-4986-98EC-8F0614619365/Q Hamp.app/Dee Q’s/Q Hamp. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: what are you doing when it crashes etc?

Comment: @Woodstock, trying to install app on device/simulator.

Comment: interesting, can you try and **reset** the simulator, also add an exception break point?

Comment: When the app crashes, there will be a backtrace.   Show the backtrace.

Comment: @bbum, it was a bad mistake, don't know from whom? (me or Apple). By mistake I changed Product Name inside Build Settings. Before it was "DeeQHamp", but then I changed it to "DeeQ's/Hamp" and then the problem started. I reverse it to an original name and now its working fine.

Comment: I'm betting that '/' caused the NSBundle subsystem to lose track of the app's files.   Sounds like two bugs;  Xcode shouldn't have allowed the edit in the first place and there should be a validation somewhere that spits an error if a product name contains a bad character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bbum, it was a bad mistake, don't know from whom? (me or Apple). By mistake, I changed Product Name inside Build Settings. Before it was "DeeQHamp", but then I changed it to "DeeQ's/Hamp" and then the problem started. I reverse it to an original name and now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please use Exceptional break point to find where app is crashing [image]

Comment: That isn't an exception based crash.